# Python Selenium Find Element by X Path Only under that Class Name

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to apply find_element_by_xpath only on specific classnames

```
textboxes = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("freebirdFormviewerViewNumberedItemContainer")
for element in textboxes:


    a = element.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'i')]")
```

I want to find the element by x path that contains the first item that has "id" in it, as there could be multiples in that node e.g "id1", "id2"

The problem is that it keeps returning the same id i.e "id1" despite me using the for loop.
Does it not loop through different element in the textboxes list? I want to apply the find_element_by_xpath only under that child node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to the right solution but missing a small point `.` :)
So inside the for loop you should use `a = element.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(@id, 'i')]")`
I mean the `.` before the `//` at the beginning of the `xpath` expression.
Also possibly there is a problem with `i` inside the `contains(@id, 'i')` - I don't see where you are updating it's value.

To find the `input` element you can simply use the following `css selector` `.freebirdFormviewerViewNumberedItemContainer input` or if you prefer `xpath` you can use `//div[@class='freebirdFormviewerViewNumberedItemContainer']//input`

Answer (score 0):

You are not augmenting `i` inside your loop, so it just stays the same for every iteration.

Comment: No, he is missing `.` as i mentioned. Without it `find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'i')]")` returns the first element in the entire page located by that `xpath` and not inside any other specified element. That's why `.` like `from here` stands for/